# Is there a way to use one Timer for multiple events?

Tags: c#, timer, event-handling, .net-3.5

I am in C# .NET 3.5
What happens when timer elapses and event handler is performed ?
Does the timer cease to exist ?
Can I register several events in different time on one timer, expecting them all to fire one after another ?

Comment: A timer can time only one interval.  That's good enough to time any number of events, you just have to set the interval to the earliest one that's due.

Comment: @Grant
I agree it should not cease to exist without Disposing/deleting it.

I also assume, it (registering several Ticks) should be possible. But probably the behavior will be dependent on type of timer. There are 3 (+1 in asp) that I know in .NET. So I wonder, if /which of them will give me desired separate events firing in expected time distance.

Comment: @Hans
Can U please rephrase "you just have to set the interval to the earliest one that's due. "
I am not sure if I got your point correctly.

Comment: Say you have 4 appointments today and you have only one wrist-watch.   You have no trouble being on time for all 4, do you?  Just do the same in code.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a timer to fire off the event only once or continue to do it (Timer.AutoReset property).  Yes, you can register several different event handlers on a single timer, but I don't know that there is any way of knowing what order they will fire.  If that matters to you, set a single handler, and have that handler call the others.  If what you are trying to do is to call a different handler, each time the timer goes off, I would suggest setting a single handler that keeps an enum indicating which function to call and incrementing it each time it gets called by the timer.

To call the same handler to "iterate" through a list of parameters, once on each interval elapsed, I would have an array or list of the parameters and the handler would just increase a counter or consume the list.

```
using System.Timers;

public class MyTimedDelete {

  private static List<int> ListOfIds=null;
  private static System.Timers.Timer myTimer=null;

  public static void AddIdToQueue(int id)
  {
      if (ListOfIds == null)
      {
         ListOfIds = new List<int>();
         myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
         myTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
      }

      ListOfIds.Add(id);
      if (ListOfIds.Count==1)
      {
          myTimer.Start();
      }    
  }

  private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
  {
      deleteItem(ListOfIds[0]);
      ListOfIds.RemoveAt(0);
      if (ListOfIds.Count == 0) {
          myTimer.Stop();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd need to launch same handler, with different parameter (id of a message to be deleted).

Comment: at different times?  Same interval or different intervals?

Comment: Then something like the code I have added to my answer above should work. right?

Comment: This solution is known. You suggest to create new Timer in  SomeFunction but I need 1 universal Timer to start extra countdown (same period) when msg arrives. When period elapses, Timer would fire elapsed event handler with msgId as parameter. That message would be deleted from queue.

Comment: Then that is just an extension of what I had.  I have expanded in detail above, in the code.  If you have a class like this, from anywhere in your code, you can call MyTimedDelete.AddIdToQueue(x); to add an id to the queue and have the timed event call your deleteItem function with that id after an elapsed time.  I have not built this class, so I may have typos in there.  Up to you to build and test.

Comment: I have modified the code, is this any closer to what you needed?

Comment: @Gichrist
Thanx for the post. This one is closer to what I needed. But as I mentioned, I need to fire the OnTimedEvent with an extra parameter - msgId, so that I don't rely on the time sequence, that I delete the correct message. Furthermore I need to stop the timer, if acknowledge is received to the message (i.e. msgId) I sent. In this case, I need to stop the timer for this msgId only, so that the OnTimedEvent with this msgId is not called.
In worst case, I could ignore that call, but its not clean solution.

Your post is interesting though, so I  voted 1+
Thanx again.